# How do I list vertices in the order I select them in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I'm writing a tool for may that returns the vertices in the same order as selected, but I get them in numerical order.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.selectPref(tso=True)

print(cmds.ls( orderedSelection=True))
print(cmds.ls( sl=True,))
```

Comment: It's possible, but you need to not have anything selected, run 

`cmds.selectPref(tso=True)`

Then separately run 

`print(cmds.ls( orderedSelection=True))`
But that's really inconvenient and Preferences > Setting > Selection > Track Selection Order does nothing.

Comment: note that if you select with anykind loop, it won't retain anything. it really need to select one by one the components

Comment: Okay, now this works, even though when I tried it before, it didn't.

`
import maya.cmds as cmds

if (cmds.selectPref(tso=True, q=True)==0):
    cmds.selectPref(tso=True)

print(cmds.ls( orderedSelection=True))`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this started working, when I had tried it before and it didn't

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

if (cmds.selectPref(tso=True, q=True)==0):
    cmds.selectPref(tso=True)
print(cmds.ls( orderedSelection=True))
```